# Establishing a Single Node K8 cluster utilizing Rancher

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I'm new to the world of Kubernetes and I'm attempting to work my way through understanding its environment. I've been tasked with installing and spinning up a cluster on a single Ubuntu server.

The requirements:
All functionality must be self-contained to the single server
Must utilize Rancher
Must be able to use Podman in place of Docker

This is just a development environment for now to sandbox with, but this is what I've been directed to work with.

My current environment:
For now, I'm testing everything out on a Ubuntu 22.04 VM. Its been set up using VB, the network adapter is bridged to give ssh access from the host machine. No other configuration has been done

Steps I've taken:
I've gone through a number of tutorials, and most of which has required me to install Rancher as a Docker container. I want to avoid using the Docker container and would prefer to work with Rancher directly as a standard install.

So I've followed the instructions via Ranchers How to guides, Specifically the [Setting up a High-availability RKE Kubernetes Cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SowTO.png)

- Required Tools:
  Both kubectl and RKE have been installed per the instructions available.

  ```
    kubectl

         a.    First verify the latest version compatible with Rancher
         i.    Support Matrix (latest 1.26)
         b.    sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl
         c.    curl -fsSL https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb/Release.key |                                           
              sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg
         d.    echo 'deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg]               
              https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb/ /' | sudo tee 
              /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
         e.    sudo apt update
         f.    Update to correct version
         i.    vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
              1.   edit version #
         g.    sudo apt install -y kubectl

    rke
         a.    visit RKE Release page
         b.    wget <release link>
         i.    wget https://github.com/rancher/rke/releases/download/v1.4.10/rke_linux-              
              amd64
         c.    chmod +x rke_linux-amd64
         d.    mv rke_linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/rke
  ```

At this point I followed the instructions for creating the cluster configuration file. At the top of the page I used the information for creating a single node. The fact the node would have to include *etcd*, *controlplane*, and *worker* roles. The cluster config file looks like this

```
nodes:
     - address: <ip of vm>
       user: <username>
       role:
           - controlplane
           - etcd
           - worker
```

From my understanding, this is the simplest configuration I could use for verification. When I run *rke up* it looks like it's working, but then I come across a warning and an error.

[image: Error]

However, the error is much more of a concern. I've found several posts, but I can't make heads or tails of whats happening.

[stackoverflow result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949639/how-to-fix-cluster-must-have-at-least-one-etcd-plane-host-failed-to-connect-to) its talking about docker, which means to me I should have it installed, however, as I mentioned before, we need to be using Podman.

There is very little information that I can find that is related to use of Podman in place of Docker in regards to rancher.

I hoping someone has some insights as to what next steps I should take.